# Permission denied when trying to 'mv' a directory

Tags: mv, permission-denied, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Situation:

- I am using *Bash with Linux subsystem* for Windows(10); I am logged in as *root*.
- All folders and files in my current directory have *rwxrwxrwx*, and the same is true for descendant files and folders.
- There is no system file in my current directory nor in the
  descendants.
- None of folders is synchronized with *git*.

Problem:

- I cannot change the name of one particular directory.  However I can do
  this for every single other directory or file - whether in the current
  directory, or inside the un-`mv`-able directory in question.

I can copy a whole directory to another one and then freely change its name, or I can copy its contents to the folder with the desired name, and those solutions are acceptable, but using just `mv` would be easier. For the sake of knowledge - as a `bash` and *Linux* beginner - I really would like to understand the problem.

---

**Additional info as requested**

```
root@MARVIN:/mnt/h/testing# mv test1.pl otherName
mv: cannot move ‘test1.pl’ to ‘otherName’: Permission denied
```

```
root@MARVIN:/mnt/h/testing# lsattr test1.pl
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on test1.pl/css
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on test1.pl/fonts
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on test1.pl/index.html
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on test1.pl/index2.html
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on test1.pl/index3.html
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on test1.pl/index4.html
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on test1.pl/index5.html
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on test1.pl/js
lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device While reading flags on test1.pl/notes.txt
```

Given various operations I was doing on partition *directory* resides on, I guess it is not read-only, but for the record:

```
root@MARVIN:/mnt/h/testing# mount
rootfs on / type rootfs (rw,relatime)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=204320k,mode=755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=102400k,mode=755)
```

---

**Solution**

The directory was in fact blocked by Atom editor (installed on *Windows* not *WSL*).

***Details***

[image]

The directory in question is directory A.

- If one of files Aa, Ab, Ac is opened in the editor, I can `mv` Dir A.
- If one of files AAa ... ABc is opened I get `Permission denied`.
- If contents of Dir A are visible it Atom project browser, I can `mv` it.
- If contents of Dir AA or Dir AB are visible in Atom p. b., I get `Permission denied`.

Comment: do `lsattr <directory>` please and share the output

Comment: Does your unmovable files is residing in  any readonly partition?

Comment: Perhaps it would help if you could post the output of `pwd` and both the `mv` command you are trying and its output.

Comment: Question was updated with all requested info.

Comment: Does `otherName` already exist (including all variations, capitalized or not)? Have `test1.pl` or `H:\testing` recently been modified by an ordinary (non-WSL) Windows program?

Comment: `otherName` does not exist; sibling-directories to the directory in question could have their names changed to `otherName` without a problem. About the modification - AFAIK: no. I may add that `test1.pl` is directory for the virtual host of Apache, but still, as well are neighbouring directories that could be `mv`-ed freely.

Comment: I have inadvertently killed experimental subject. To verify if directory is attached to some Windows service I copied it and tried to remove it - sadly not with Windows "delete" but `rm -r`. Much to my surprise directory vanished without a single objection. I then renamed the copy of directory to the original name `test1.pl` and now I obviously can `mv` it, but further troubleshooting may be difficult. I will report if the problem will come back after next reboot.

Comment: If this happens again, try renaming it in windows explorer - it might give a more precise error message.

Comment: @Mark Plotnick I updated my question. I guess your suggestion that Windows program modifies this directory was correct, but - at least for me - it was happening in a hard to notice way.

Comment: More details:

https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/3738
https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1529

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think that a service or a program of windows is perhaps using or accessing the same file , i used to have the same problem when i first installed  the linux subsystem on windows 10.

Comment: In my case, I just closed VSCode and it worked.